# Unable to launch dsa.msc as a different user

Tags: active-directory

I'm facing a huge issue, I cannot work in our AD anymore, because windows cannot find the dsa.msc file.

Usually, I run Active Directory Users and Computers as my admin account. When entering credentials, I have the following:

[image: cred]

If I connect my self from an other computer, this is working fine and I can deal with users & groups.

I've change my password, reinstall all that is related to AD managment, but I can't even imagine restaging my machine. I've deleted temp files also.
This is clearly not a account issue. Even my server team could not help.

Answer (score 0):

From which computer are you trying to do this? 
Is this a client computer or a server? Generally you cannot open dsa.msc from a client computer if the Remote Server Administration Tools are not installed on it. 
Is this a Domain Controller?